# Has anyone run an objective comparison of Nessus and Skipfish

Tags: security

We recently set up Nessus, but the annual cost is not cheap. Recently Google published [SkipFish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) which appears to compete in the area of webapps.

As best I can tell, Nessus operates via **a large database** of known exploits. And, as best as I can tell, Skipfish automatically **generates vulnerability tests**. Has anyone done a comparison of the effectiveness of these two approaches yet?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered OpenVAS?  It forked from Nessus when they closed source.  Nessus and OpenVAS as opposed to SkipFish are less Web application focused and intended to cover a variety of daemons.

What are the requirements you're trying to meet?

Comment: openvas is a hard way to go, its lacking in docs and userbase

Answer (score 2):

Skipfish and Nessus have different objectives (although they share some checks).

- skipfish is web vulnerability scanner: its mission is to find web apps vulnerabilities. On the lines of w3af and webscarab (but different).
- Nessus is a vulnerability port scanner: its mission is to find vulnerabilities on open ports on a system. Besides, Nessus can also do compliance audits.

That said, Nessus also does some basic web vulnerability scanning that improves when used alongside nikto.

I don't know how you could compare them, knowing that they would output different kind of information.